# Visual Studio 15 выдает ошибку, которой нет

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, cocos2d

Я установил движок cocos2d-x-3.16 на VS15. Прекомпилятор выдает несколько ошибок, но ошибок как таковых нет и всё компилируется и работает. Могу привести пример на скринах. Может знает как это исправить? Снизу скрины с пвсевдо ошибками.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте rebuild, иногда помогает

Comment: "Прекомпилятор выдает несколько ошибок" - что такое прекомпилятор? какие ошибки он выдает? "но ошибок как таковых нет" так они есть или нет? Вы случаем не путаете ошибки компиляции и ошибки IntelliSense?

Comment: Полагаю, что @VTT прав и спрашивающий путает Intellisense с компиляцией. Ничего ужасного в этом нет, частенько данная "умная" штука при работе с кокосом несет больше вреда, выдавая ложные ошибки. Т.к. работаю с кокосом каждый день - отключил отображение ошибок IS через настройки.